# Задача на Многопоточное программирование C#

Tags: c#

Хелп):

**C#**: Дана последовательность натуральных чисел {a0…an–1}. Создать многопоточное приложение для поиска минимального ai. Количество потоков является входным параметром программы, потоки проводят вычисления независимо друг от друга, количество символов в строке может быть не кратно количеству потоков.

Comment: Самый простой вариант, и самый нежелательный - `for (var q=i; q<n; q+=k)`.

Comment: Вариант получше: `var l = n / k * i;
var r = k == k-1 ? n : n / k * (i + 1);
for (var q=l; q<r; ++q)` но последняя секция может быть длиннее остальных на `k-1` элемент - лучше бы их разбросать равномерно между первыми потоками.

Comment: А не могли бы вы написать полноценный код, который можно вставить и запустить? А то вообще не догоняю, а так хотя бы что то понял

Comment: Я написал то, как разделить массив на части, обрабатываемые `i`м потоком из `k` потоков. У тебя вопрос ещё затрагивает агрегацию результатов работы потоков, так что так что пока нет.

Comment: Ну ладно, все равно спасибо, постараюсь как то сам)

Comment: @Qwertiy А зачем так заморачиваться? Parallel.ForEach и в путь. Нет?

Comment: @iluxa1810, мне казалось, что он сам определяет число потоков, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy по умолчанию да, но можно ему параметры подсунуть https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: MaxDegreeOfParallelism 
Gets or sets the maximum number of concurrent tasks enabled by this ParallelOptions instance.

Comment: Конечно, задача может носить академический характер и нужно реально управлять потоками руками. Тогда да, не подойдет.

Comment: @iluxa1810, но это ж максимум. Он не обязан делать ровно столько?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, наверное, в некоторых случаях он может не создать максимальное кол-во потоков. Например, при очень маленьких коллекциях.

Comment: @iluxa1810, ну при маленьких было бы и самому тупо создавать больше потоков, чем там элементов.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну... Все зависит от постановки задачи. Если задаваемое число потоков- это такое же максимальное число потоков, то Parallel.ForEach прокатит.